# bootstrap accordion - keep fix position of lower contents

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I am new to css.
Currently when we click on the `anchor "Collapsible Group Item"`, it opens the panel body,and the below label is shifted below. I want to keep my accordion contents to be overlapped, so that the lower content's position will not resize, their position will be fixed.In this case it should be overlapped on the `"success" label`.

here is jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/pmd/g8V7Q/4/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you need to adjust default bootstrap css behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use CSS to absolute position the panel when it's opened like this..

```
#accordion .collapsing, #accordion .collapse.in
{
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 20;
  width: auto;
  overflow:visible;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/6e0pnrm7fL

Comment: Hi, I used this code too, but my collapsable still animates the page and then becomes an hover. How can i prevent the animation?

I added myself for .panel a relative position and for the .collapse a width of 100%